# Hard disk detected for Linux installation but fail to boot: OS or hardware issue?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, bios, bootable-media

I have an SGI server (SGI C4002 Server, 2016) where I can install Linux.

The problem is that at boot, the BIOS claims that there is no boot media, even when the hard disk is there. I used three different well functioning hard disks.

The hard disk is listed in the BIOS and it is found for installation from different tested Linux distributions like Debian, Ubuntu and OpenSUSE, but not for booting.

Comment: Do not know servers, but UEFI or BIOS install? And then is system set to boot in that boot mode? Boot of flash drive UEFI or BIOS is how it is installed. But settings in UEFI determine default boot mode of an installed system. Install & boot mode must match.

Comment: @oldfred I will have to talk the TI guys how they are trying now, but when I tried, I take care of that issue.